# Ajax response not returning

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am having a table with data where I have an action button in last column to delete that particular row. I want to make the delete via ajax and without refreshing the page. I am using the following code but their is no response coming from the ajax page. Also the queries at the ajax page is not executing. Can I have some insight over what could be possibly wrong.

```
      <a href="#" class="btnIcon    glyphicon glyphicon-trash delbutton" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete" id="<?php echo $id; ?>"></a>

 <script type="text/javascript" >
        $(function() {

            $(".delbutton").click(function() {
                var del_id = $(this).attr("id");
                var info = 'id=' + del_id;
                var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');

                if (confirm("Sure you want to delete this post? This cannot be undone later.")) {

                    $.ajax({
                        type : "POST",
                        url : "delete_entry.php", //URL to the delete php script
                        data: info,
                    success : function(response) {
                               if(response=='deletion success'){
                                $tr.find('td').fadeOut(1000,function(){ $tr.remove();  }); 

                               }
                        }
                    });  
                }
                return false;
            });
        });
 </script>
```

And at `delete_entry.php`

```
 <?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');  

session_start();

require("../config.php"); 
require("../Database.class.php"); 
require("../site.php"); 
$db = new Database(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_DATABASE);     
$fnc=new site_functions($db);

    $id     =   $_POST['id'];

    $deleted_date = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
  $deleted_by       =    $_SESSION['session_admin_id'] ;

  $nots = $db->idToField("tbl_ques","notes",$id);
   if ($nots == "")
   {
   $date_string = "last deleted on|".$deleted_date."|" ;
   }
   else {
   $date_string = $nots."last deleted on|".$deleted_date."|" ;
   }
     $fnc->update_is_not_deleted_for_Pearsonvue("tbl_ques",$id, "$deleted_date", $deleted_by);       
    $notes_data = array("notes"=>$date_string);

  if($db->query_update("tbl_ques", $notes_data, "id=$id")){
      http_response_code();        
      echo json_encode('deletion success');
    }else{
       http_response_code(204);       
    }

?>
```

Comment: You are not sending any json response from php to the javascript. Also you have not done any operations based on the ajax response.

Comment: Your PHP script does not actually end with `</script>` for no reason, right?

Comment: @DroidDev thanks for the comment. but i want to know why the queries are not being executed on delete_entry.php

Comment: Also $fnc is not defined. You should use this in ajax parameters 'dataType: "json"', and in php you should to return json

Comment: I have only sent the `<script>` part. Its basically in a php file. @04FS

Comment: @IvanKaraivanov Yeah I have commented that part. I want to know how can I debug this to see which all statements are being executed on delete_entry.php

Comment: What if I wan to send a message that 'record deleted successfully' on successful query execution?

Comment: @Andy you can debug the using Network under Inspect Element(right click in page) in Firefox. Also using Network under Inspect in chrome.

Comment: put the statement in if condition, like this

```if($db->query_update("tbl_question", $notes_data, "id=$id")){
echo json_encode('deletion success');
}```

Comment: ok. and how to display it on my page from where the request is being sent @DroidDev

Comment: @Andy After update you need to slow the animation, correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206802/discussion-between-droiddev-and-andy).

Answer (score 0):

Change your java script function as below

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
        $(function() {

            $(".delbutton").click(function() {
                var del_id = $(this).attr("id");
                var info = 'id=' + del_id;
                if (confirm("Sure you want to delete this post? This cannot be undone later.")) {

                    $.ajax({
                        type : "POST",
                        url : "delete_entry.php", //URL to the delete php script
                        data: info,
           //changes from 
                       success : function(response) {
                               if(response=='deletion success'){  
                           $(this).parents(".record").animate("fast").animate({
                                 opacity : "hide"
                           }, "slow");
                               }
                        }
                    });  
            //changes to                  
                }
                return false;
            });
        });
  </script>
```

Also change you php file

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');  // Add this line its must

session_start();

 $db = new Database(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_DATABASE);     


    $id     =   $_POST['id'];

    $deleted_date = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
  $deleted_by       =    $_SESSION['session_admin_id'] ;

  $nots = $db->idToField("tbl_question","notes",$id);
   if ($nots == "")
   {
   $date_string = "last deleted on|".$deleted_date."|" ;
   }
   else {
   $date_string = $nots."last deleted on|".$deleted_date."|" ;
   }

      $fnc->update_is_not_deleted_for_Pearsonvue("tbl_question",$id, "$deleted_date", $deleted_by);       
    $notes_data = array("notes"=>$date_string);
//changes from
    if($db->query_update("tbl_question", $notes_data, "id=$id")){
      http_response_code();        
      echo json_encode('deletion success');
    }else{
       http_response_code(204);       
    }
//changes to
?>
```